# Placing values generated from one sheet, into a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a nested `for loop` that is looking to take values in one row, generate a value based on an equation, then do the same for many rows following the first one, all while adding the value together.

Essentially, if row one has a value of 15, and row 2 and 3 return values of 10 and 12, the variable storing the total value (named `genCost`) will be 37.

I want to place the summed total values of `genCost` in a new sheet, separated by day, but when I run the code I get a Run-time 1004 error.  I realize that this has something to do with the sheet that I am working on, and the sheet that I am trying to place the values into (the 2nd to last line in the code).

I understand my code may be ugly and simple, but can somebody help me troubleshoot this?

```
'Nested For loop for ALL OTHER DAYS of genCost...only 1 formula
For j = 2 To dayNumber
    For i = 1 To increments

        'IF(AND(U7=1,U6=0),R7,0)
        If Cells(rowValue, 21) = 1 And Cells(rowValue - 1, 21) = 0 Then
            ifValue = Cells(rowValue, 18)
        Else
            ifValue = 0
        End If

        'calculate value variable with second half of equation
        value = (((Cells(rowValue, 23) * Cells(rowValue, 16) * (1 / 6)) + (Cells(rowValue, 25) * Cells(rowValue, 17) * (1 / 6)) + (Cells(rowValue, 21) * Cells(rowValue, 19) * (1 / 6)) + ifValue))
        genCost = genCost + value

        'set value and ifValue back to zero and step down one row and do again
        value = 0
        ifValue = 0
        rowValue = rowValue + 1

    Next i

Cells(3, j) = genCost
Dim genCostRefNum As Integer: genCostRefNum = 6
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(genCostRefNum, 4)) = genCost
genCost = 0

Next j
```

Comment: I'm going to bet it's because you need to clarify the Range type references.  You need to tell it what sheet to get `Cells(genCostRefNum,4)` from.  If it's Sheets(1), then just fix it like so: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(genCostRefNum, 4)) = genCost`.  Try that and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  But perhaps I may be not understanding fully.  In actuality, the value is being generated from inputs in sheet 2 (though never actually placed into any cell, anywhere), and I want to take that value and place it in sheet 1.  In your tip above, you mention that I need to tell Excel what sheet to get the value from.  Since I am only trying to place the value into sheet 1, is this still the way you were thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(genCostRefNum, 4)) = genCost
```

write this

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(genCostRefNum, 4) = genCost
```

There is a default property of `Cells` statement, which is `Value` (same for `Range`). So your code was exactly

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(genCostRefNum, 4).Value).Value = genCost
```

and after executing `Cells` something like:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(6).Value = genCost
```

It's good practice to always write complete statements and don't rely on default properties.